# How can I ensure columns wrap equally in Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I have an unknown number of items to display, each within their own column, is there a way to get them to wrap equally without having to create new rows for each?

I have

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- 1st col --><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><h1>Title lorem</h1><p>Short</p></div>
    <!-- 2nd col --><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><h1>Title lorem</h1><p>Description lorem</p></div>
    ...
    <!-- nth col --><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><h1>Title lorem</h1><p>Description lorem that might be long</p></div>
</div>
```

The columns will have varying heights, which can sometimes lead to unequally distributed columns:

[image]

Is it possible to get the columns to always wrap in rows of 4 columns (for medium), 3 columns (for small), or 2 columns (for extra-small) with just CSS, or will I need some JS or to use some server side programming to create new rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats unfortunately not how the grid works. You could use something like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or have different containers generated for each breakpoint with php. e.g.:

```
<div class ="visible-xs"><div class ="row">... </div></div>
<div class ="visible-sm"><div class ="row">... </div></div>
<div class ="visible-md"><div class ="row">... </div></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can also try using css-columns in combination with media queries, if cross-browser is not too much of a concern for you.

Answer (score 15):

There [is the way to clear Bootstrap columns](http://www.bluthemes.com/blog/3/clearing-bootstrap-3-columns) as mentioned by Maciej. This can be done this way:

```
 .col-lg-3:nth-child(4n+1){
   clear: left;
 }
```

The article contains full source which makes it work universally from `sm` to `lg`.

Comment: thank you! this really saved the day.. also just a note but it only works if all cols are of the same size.

Answer (score 13):

If I understood your problem correctly, it should be enough to just apply `.clearfix` accordingly after each set of elements that need to be in one line.

Check the [example](http://bootply.com/93537)

And alternative solution is to use CSS `:nth-child` pseudo-class in combination with media queries. For each resolution, there would be a different `n-th` element with `clear:both`, that would create a new row.

Take a look at a [quick overview how to use :nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/).

Comment: Thank you--+1 for the example. Looks good but requires knowing which content will be longer than the others, and since I'm populating from a DB I won't know ahead of time.

Comment: Works perfectly. This should be the accepted answer, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Use Responsive Column Resets: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

I was creating an event viewer that would show 12 different events. In large mode I wanted them 4x3, medium 3x4, small 2x6, and x-small just stacked.

```
<div>
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 1</div>
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 2</div>  

          <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>

       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 3</div>

          <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>

       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 4</div>

          <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block visible-lg-block"></div>

       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 5</div>
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 6</div>

          <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block visible-md-block"></div>

       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 7</div>
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 8</div>    

          <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block visible-lg-block"></div>

       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 9</div>

          <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>

       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 10</div>    

          <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>

       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 11</div>
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Text 12</div>
</div>
```